# start date & end date from table in generate_series()

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

I am trying to count business days between a certain date range in PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT 
     SUM(CASE WHEN extract (dow FROM foo) IN(1,2,3,4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END) 
FROM (SELECT ('2007-04-01'::date + 
(generate_series(0,'2007-04-30'::date 
 - '2007-04-01'::date)||'days')::interval) AS foo) foo
```

I want to replace the dates with `start_date` and `end_date` from a table named `myTable`
`start_date` and `end_date` format is `yyyy-mm-dd`

Actually I need it to display the business days date diff for each row

```
|start_date |end_date |
------------------------
|2018-04-01 |2018-04-30| 
|2018-05-01 |2018-05-30|
```

This is my code:

```
  SELECT pto.start_date, pto.end_date, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN extract (dow FROM foo) IN(1,2,3,4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as theDIFF 
  FROM (
  SELECT start_date, (start_date::date + 
  (generate_series(0,end_date::date 
    - start_date::date)||'days')::interval) AS foo
  FROM pto
  ) foo inner join pto pto
  on pto.start_date = foo.start_date 
  group by pto.start_date, pto.end_date
```

My OUTPUT:

```
  |start_date(date)| end_date(date) |theDiff(integer)
  ---------------------------------------------------
  |2017-06-01      |  2017-06-01    |        29     |
  |2017-05-29      |  2017-06-02    |        12     |
  ---------------------------------------------------
```

Expected Output:

```
  |start_date(date)| end_date(date) |theDiff(integer)
  ---------------------------------------------------
  |2017-06-01      |  2017-06-01    |        1      |
  |2017-05-29      |  2017-06-02    |        5      |
  ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: From which row of the table do you want to take the values?

Comment: The statement as shown is invalid because you need a `group by` for the `sum()` - do you have any other columns in that table? What is the primary key?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that solves my error but my calculations are messed up. For 2017-06-01 - 2017-06-01 , I am getting 29.

Comment: You should really show us the complete table structure and the result you expect.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added the table structure and the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code is a bit confusing, so just considering business days and your table, this will give expected output:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (start_date date, end_date date);

INSERT INTO myTable VALUES('2017-06-01', '2017-06-01'),('2017-05-29', '2017-06-02');

SELECT start_date, end_date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(dow FROM days) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM myTable
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1 day') AS days
 GROUP BY start_date, end_date;
```

It will generate rows, each having start_date, end_date and one day in between those. Then it will agregate by start_date, end_date and SUM() dates that have day of week between 1 and 5 (monday-friday).

Without aggregation it looks like this:

```
 start_date |  end_date  |          days          | dow
------------+------------+------------------------+-----
 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-01 00:00:00+02 |   4
 2017-05-29 | 2017-06-02 | 2017-05-29 00:00:00+02 |   1
 2017-05-29 | 2017-06-02 | 2017-05-30 00:00:00+02 |   2
 2017-05-29 | 2017-06-02 | 2017-05-31 00:00:00+02 |   3
 2017-05-29 | 2017-06-02 | 2017-06-01 00:00:00+02 |   4
 2017-05-29 | 2017-06-02 | 2017-06-02 00:00:00+02 |   5
```

And group by:

```
 start_date |  end_date  | sum
------------+------------+-----
 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-01 |   1
 2017-05-29 | 2017-06-02 |   5
```